# Italian phone 10-digit number regex issue

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use the regex from [this site](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/regular-expression-examples/#phonenumber-italy)

```
/^([+]39)?((38[{8,9}|0])|(34[{7-9}|0])|(36[6|8|0])|(33[{3-9}|0])|(32[{8,9}]))([\d]{7})$/
```

for **italian mobile phone numbers** but a simple number as 3491234567 results invalid.

*(don't care about spaces as i'll trim them)*

```
should pass:
349 1234567
+39 349 1234567
TODO: 0039 349 1234567
TODO: (+39) 349 1234567
TODO: (0039) 349 1234567
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/) and [regexr](http://regexr.com/) both pass the validation..what's wrong?

**UPDATE:**

To clarify:
The regex should match any number that starts with either

388/389/380 `(38[{8,9}|0])|`

or
347/348/349/340 `(34[{7-9}|0])|`

or
366/368/360 `(36[6|8|0])|`

or
333/334/335/336/337/338/339/330 `(33[{3-9}|0])|`

328/329 `(32[{8,9}])`

plus 7 digits `([\d]{7})`

and the +39 at the start optionally `([+]39)?`

Comment: I'd advise to be very careful when you see a regex with pipes inside `[...]`. This site is not to be trusted as far as regexes are concerned then. How do you use the regex? Please post the code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why should I be careful on regex with pipes?

Comment: Because it is most likely a human error. I meant pipes in character classes, not pipes in patterns. BTW, what is `{3-9}`  supposed to mean here? It matches literally `{3-9}`. Is there such a phone part in Italian numbers? How do you dial `{`? `[{8,9}|0]` matches 1 symbol: either `{` or `8`, or `,` or `9`... Are there commas in Italian phone numbers? Do not use this regex, write your own one, it is junk.

Comment: I think you refer to the `(36[6|8|0])` part, didn't noticed that. Anyways I think it was meant to validate a number starting with `36` and ending with `6` OR `8` OR `0`. Is that part right?

Comment: No, no, no. The pattern is junk. Find the requirements, and write the correct pattern from scratch.

Comment: Thank you, I never wrote one and merely used them, that's why I used that snipped. I guess the part {3-9} should match any nember **between** 3 and 9. I was trying to find a way to do that quicly without having to learn Regex from scratch

Comment: Then use `[3-9]`. But how can you know what `[{8,9}|0]` is supposed to mean? `8` or `9` or `0`? Then it must be written as `[089]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105363/discussion-between-alexander-d-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: For what it's worth, the Stack Overflow [regex tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) covers this particular error, and has pointers to several useful resources for resolving this. You should check it out and perhaps then [edit] your question to refactor out the common beginner errors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following regex appears to fulfill your requirements.  I took out the syntax errors and guessed a bit, and added the missing parts to cover your TODO comments.

```
^(\((00|\+)39\)|(00|\+)39)?(38[890]|34[7-90]|36[680]|33[3-90]|32[89])\d{7}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yF7bZ0/1

Your test cases fail to cover many of the variations captured by the regex; perhaps you'll want to beef up the test set to make sure it does what you want.

The beginning allows for an optional international prefix with or without the parentheses.  The basic pattern is `(00|\+)39` and it is repeated with or without parentheses around it.  (Perhaps a better overall approach would be to trim parentheses and punctuation as well as whitespace before processing begins; you'll want to keep the plus as significant, of course.)

Updated with information from @Edoardo's answer; wrapped for legibility and added comments:

```
^                           # beginning of line
(\((00|\+)39\)|(00|\+)39)?  # country code or trunk code, with or without parentheses
(                           # followed by one of the following
 32[89]|                    # 328 or 329
 33[013-9]|                 # 33x where x != 2
 34[04-9]|                  # 34x where x not in 1,2,3
 35[01]|                    # 350 or 351
 36[068]|                   # 360 or 366 or 368
 37[019]                    # 370 or 371 or 379
 38[089])                   # 380 or 388 or 389
\d{6,7}                     # ... followed by 6 or 7 digits
$                           # and end of line
```

There are obvious accidental gaps which will probably also get filled over time. Generalizing this further is likely to improve resilience toward future changes, but of course may at the same time increase the risk of false positives. Make up your mind about which is worse.

Comment: I'll do, thanks. Your expression is fine for now, I'll investigate further asap. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I found this and i updated with new operators and MVNO prefixes (Iliad, ho.)

```
^(\((00|\+)39\)|(00|\+)39)?(38[890]|34[24-90]|36[680]|33[13-90]|32[890]|35[013]|37[0139]|39[23])\d{6,7}$
```

Comment: If you can explain what that means and/or link to further information, I can probably also update my answer to keep it current. What's MVNO? Who's Iliad here? (A phone operator, apparently?)

Comment: MVNO are "virtual operators", and they have their own prefixes.
Iliad started last year in italy as main operator, and it has 351 prefix assigned.
Also fixed the 34x series, because it accepted only 347-8-9-0, but we have 344 and 345 numbers.

PS: I wanted to comment your answer instead of adding new one, but i have no reputation enough. BTW thank you, it was best answer i found before

Comment: Also changed final digit count. There are old numbers like 333 123456 still used.

Answer (score 2):

I improved the regex adding the case to handle space between numbers:

```
^(\((00|\+)39\)|(00|\+)39)?(38[890]|34[4-90]|36[680]|33[13-90]|32[89]|35[01]|37[019])(\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3,4}|\d{6,7})$
```

so, for example, I can match phone number like this (0039) 349 123 4567 or this 349 123 4567

Answer (score 1):

Following doc:

https://it.qaz.wiki/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Italy

A simple regex for MOBILE italian numbers without special chars is:

/^3[0-9]{8,9}$/

it match a string starting with the digit '3' and followed by 8 or 9 digits, ex:

3345678103

you can add then ITALIAN prefix like '+39 ' or '0039 '

/^+39 3[0-9]{8,9}$/ --- match --> +39 3345678103

/^\0039 3[0-9]{8,9}$/ --- match --> 0039 3345678103

Comment: I would add an OR for the prefix. Something like that might do the trick `^((?:0039)?|(?:\+39)?)3[0-9]{8,9}$`